# Plot explanation about the gambling in Everybody Hates Chris

Tags: plot-explanation, everybody-hates-chris

There's a little confusion with *Everybody Hates Gambling* (Season 2, Episode 19). Chris becomes an odds-maker and his father ends up placing a bet on the Phoenix over the Lakers. When Chris's mom finds out of the gambling going on, Chris tells her that he lied about the odds. So now Julius should think that it is the Lakers that would win instead. When the results turn out that the Phoenix had actually won, why is Julius all excited? Also what's up with the Bookie? First he threatens Chris and now he shows up at the door to talk to him about what?